# Apple Store Purchase history

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

Knowing I can't get rid of the purchase history at all, I've removed payment details and changed the email address from one@whatever.com to a fake one.

Then started using a new one, two@whatever.com. I have purchased several apps.

I was wondering, if I add the first email address now (one@whatever.com) as a secondary e-mail address to this two@whatever.com Apple Store account, so I could log into Apple Store with that aswell, **would the account show purchases I've initially made on the previous Apple Store account** - one@whatever.com?

Comment: Or/And if I create a new Apple Store account with the initial e-mail address but different details, would the previous purchased items be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add any email address that is in use for any other Apple ID.

You cannot transfer purchases from one account to another.

You could set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) - but all that would do would be re-expose the purchase history to **both** accounts.

Comment: But that first account I had doesn't use that e-mail address anymore, as I have changed it to a random one. So the old e-mail address is not in use anymore, I assume? Question is, if I add it as a secondary e-mail address to this current/clean account, would the old purchase (made with the first email) be transferred to this new/clean account?

Comment: If the email address is no longer associated with any Apple ID then that would be possible, but it would not enable transfer of purchases. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could describe why you have done the above.  Why not keep using the first one if you still want access to what you purchased there?

But to answer your question, you will not be able to see anything other than the purchased linked to the account you logged in as.  In order to gain access to previously purchased content, you need to log in with the associated AppleID that was used to purchase them.

Comment: I have installed Tinder, a dating app, on the first account, that's why I changed the email address to a fake one and started using another account. But now I would like to use the initial email address again in order to sign in to Apple Store and I am afraid my girlfriend would see the purchased app, hence the question.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me. So I don't want to ever gain access to what I've purchased before on account 1. But if I add that e-mail address as a secondary one to the current, clean one, would the initial purchase made on the first email be shown in the purchase history?

Comment: You can hide individual purchases. I think that is a more suitable idea. Really, you question should be 'how can I hide an app purchase', as it stands you've picked the solution already, found it lacking, and are asking for help making it work.